# Is it possible to update the data of a child when the Key is generated automatically by the Firebase?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to update a specific data when the key is automatically generated by Firebase.

I tried the code bellow. It still does not work :(

I've tried this :

```
  function updateHomeworkStatus(agent) {

    var chosenHw = request.body.queryResult.outputContexts[0].parameters.chosenHw;
    var status = request.body.queryResult.outputContexts[0].parameters.status;

    var query = admin.database().ref('Homework').orderByChild('Name').equalTo(chosenHw);
    query.once('value')
      .then(snapshot => {
        // Once we have a result, we can use the reference to it
        var snapshotRef = snapshot.ref;

        // We want to change the value of Completed field, 
        // so we get a reference to that
        var completedRef = snapshotRef.child('CompletionStatus');

        // We can then set it, since we have a direct reference to the
        // field and there is nothing else that will be changed.
        completedRef.update(status);
      });

    agent.add("Status has been changed to " + status);


  }
```

For example (I've attach the picture of my firebase):

Dialogflow: What is the name of the homework that you want to change the 
            CompletionStaus of? (I've done this)

and when the user says "Coding Worksheet 7" and the desired status "Yes",
the specific data will be changed. (I need hep for this coding part).

So the expected result will be that CompletionStatus of "Coding Worksheet 7" will be changed to "No".

[image: My Firebase]

Answer (score 2):

The key problem with your current solution is that the Firebase RT Database calls are asynchronous and you are not waiting for these calls to return results before responding to your user.

Additionally, [Firebase RT Database Queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events) will return a list/collection of results. So to look at the results of your query, you must use `snapshot.forEach()` to iterate over the returned data.

If you are going to use the update operation, [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#update), the parameter you pass into the function must be an object containing the `'path/to/value': value` pairs. See this [Firebase Blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html) for further information. So for your code, you could update 'CompletionStatus' using `update({ CompletionStatus: status }) and not have to worry about using child() at all.

You also need to consider your error cases, such as non-existent files, duplicated names and Firebase RTDB errors. I have added the error-handling scaffold for these out below.

```
// somewhere near the top of your request handler
const RESULT_NOT_FOUND = -1;
const RESULT_DUPLICATED = -2;

function updateHomeworkStatus(agent) {
  var outputContext = request.body.queryResult.outputContexts[0];
  var chosenHw = outputContext.parameters.chosenHw;
  var status = outputContext.parameters.status;

  var query = admin.database().ref('Homework').orderByChild('Name').equalTo(chosenHw);

  // Remember to return the promise
  return query.once('value')
    .then(snapshot => {
      // "snapshot" is the query result, it's children contain the queried data

      if (!snapshot.hasChildren()) {
          throw RESULT_NOT_FOUND;
      } else if (snapshot.numChildren() != 1) {
          throw RESULT_DUPLICATED;
      }

      // init variable to store DatabaseReference
      var firstResultRef;

      // only one child at this point, so only called once
      snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
        firstResultRef = childSnapshot.ref;
        return true; // stop looping
      });

      // Update 'CompletionStatus' with new value (using update() to protect existing data)
      // Remember to return the promise
      return firstResultRef.update({ CompletionStatus: status });
    })
    .then(() => { // Promise.then(successHandlerFunc, errorHandlerFunc)
      // success
      agent.add("Status has been changed to " + status);
    }, (err) => {
      // failure
      if (err === RESULT_NOT_FOUND) {
        agent.add("Sorry, I couldn't find '" + chosenHw + "'.");
      } else if (err === RESULT_DUPLICATED) {
        agent.add("Sorry, I found multiple files that match '" + chosenHw + "'.");
      } else {
        // if here, a database error has occurred.
        agent.add("Sorry, I could not process that request at this time.");
        // TODO: Log error "err".
      }
    });
}
```